# How to sum N numbers using multiple processors?

Tags: c

I am trying to sum up all of the numbers. But I am trying to do it using multiple processors via MPI. This would mean that each process is responsible for adding up only their portion of the sum, and the master process adds up all those sums.

I've tried modifying the lower and upper limits by -/+ 1, but still get inconsistent results. I even tried to make it work for a non-divisible amount of processors.

Comment: Printing the range of each partial sum as well as the sum itself might help.

Comment: Learn about race conditions.

Comment: @JL2210 To my knowledge, there should be no race conditions causing this effect. I was figuring there was just a problem with the bounds/limits. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Always consider [5 Big Fat Reasons Why Mutexes Suck Big Time](https://accu.org/var/uploads/journals/Overload149.pdf) (2nd Article)

Answer (score 3):

Your bug is this:

```
    /* check for non-divisable amount of processors */       
    int remainder = curr_proc < (N % total_proc) ? 1 : 0;
    lower_limit = curr_proc * chunk_size + curr_proc;
    upper_limit = (curr_proc + 1) * chunk_size + remainder;
```

For example, if the remainder is zero, then the lower limit should be `curr_proc * chunk_size` but you're doing `curr_proc * chunk_size + curr_proc` and skipping numbers (not adding them to the sum).

It needs to be something more like:

```
    int remainder = N % total_proc;
    if(curr_proc < remainder) {
        lower_limit = curr_proc * chunk_size + curr_proc;
    } else {
        lower_limit = curr_proc * chunk_size + remainder;
    }
    if(curr_proc + 1 < remainder) {
        upper_limit= (curr_proc + 1) * chunk_size + (curr_proc + 1);
    } else {
        upper_limit= (curr_proc + 1) * chunk_size + remainder;
    }
```

Also note that with `N+1` CPUs (e.g. 101 CPUs) the processes all do a single useless addition (`0 + lower_limit`), and the main process does all of the useful additions. To get any benefit you need to limit the number of CPUs to a fraction of N (e.g. so that each CPU does at least 10 useful additions you have to limit it to no more than N/10 CPUs).

Of course "smarter" is to use pairing - e.g. "`0+100 = 1+99 = 2+98 = 3+97 = ... = 100`", which means that (by calculating the number of pairs, the sum of all pairs, and finding the "lone middle value" if there is one) you end up with something like `sum = 100/2 * 100 + 100/2`.